# How to undo svn remove

Tags: svn

Unfortunately i ran `svn remove --force <Folder_Name>` before commit.
It removed the local copy also.
I want to retrieve my folder.
Can anyone has as idea about this?

Answer (score 11):

If you deleted a versioned file, you can get it back with `svn revert`, or `svn update -r <revision>` to roll back to a particular version (e.g. if you committed the deletion).

If you deleted an unversioned file, or a file with unversioned changes, you're out of luck -- the file is deleted as `rm` would delete it, and SVN doesn't have a record of the changes.

Comment: backups rule! Even if SVN has version control.